# Where's the API documents file stored in Xcode 5?

Tags: xcode5

Just now, I updated my Xcode to 5.0, and I downloaded API documents. 
At Xcode 4.6.3 and earlier, I can find API documents files in

```
Xcode/Contents/Developer/Documentation/DocSets/
```

Now, however, I can't find again. Where are them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't check for sure because I'm on Linux machine at the moment, but I seem to recall seeing "~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets" during installation.

Comment: It really saved me a lot of bandwidth and bucks